# how to run a registraion page after adding a registration component in angular

Tags: angular

I want to run the registration page

first I create a registration page and then type ng serve command but not displaying registration page

I am writing manually on addressbar URL http://localhost:4200/app/registration

but not displaying any page
[image]

registration.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  username: any;
  empaddress: any;
  password: any;
  country: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submit() {
    console.log("username", this.username);
    console.log("empaddress", this.empaddress);
    console.log("password", this.password);
    console.log("country", this.country);
  }
}
```

registration.component.html

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label>UserName</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Employee Address</label>
    <input id="empaddress" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Country</label>
    <input id="country" type="text" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

hierarchy of project

[image]

version

- node --version
  v12.18.3
- npm --version
  6.14.6
- @angular/cli  10.0.6

I want to run the registration page by default

Comment: You have to mention the Route in app-routing.module.ts. 

__
`const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', redirectTo: registration, pathMatch: 'full' }, { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent } ]`

Comment: @NavKumarV give an error  ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts:8:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'registration'.

    8     redirectTo: registration,

Comment: see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPCwh.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to access to the component through a route (http://localhost:4200/app/registration), you must handle the routing in your application.

You need to define which component will be rendered on the route definition (i omit the 'app' route to simplify it, in order to route to http://localhost:4200/registration) :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent}
];
```

Then you need to define a router-outlet in a template to define where the component will be rendered as it can't just be rendered on his own in a SPA.

Here with AppComponent template :

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You should be able to see the content of RegistrationComponent on http://localhost:4200/registration)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the router. Your have to mention the available path at the router just like mentioned in the comments

just add this to your routes

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'registration', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
   { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent } 
 ]
```

View more exapmles to the anuglar router in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router